# jwplayer in dialog - player does not display again after closing dialog window

Tags: jquery, video, jquery-ui-dialog, jwplayer

I have an application built in XQuery that displays a video embedded on the page. I have set up a link that when clicked opens a dialog window showing the video using jwplayer. The first problem is that when you first click the link to open the dialog, the dialog window is blank until you actually click on it, then the video shows and plays fine. The second, main problem is that if you close the dialog window and then click the link to reopen it, the video does not show at all -- the dialog window is completely blank even if you click on it.

I've looked at similar posts in the JWPlayer forums and on Stackoverflow, but couldn't find an answer. There's a similar question in Stackoverflow that suggests that this issue could be solved in JWPlayer version 6.10, but I'm using version 6.12.4956. I'd appreciate it if someone could take a look and give me some suggestions.

Here is my code:

```html
<div id="video-player-container">
 <div id="video-player">{() (: This div is filled by the player :)}</div>
 <div id="video-player-modal">{() (: This div is filled by the player :)}</div>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    var options = 
     {{
       playlist:
       [{{
        sources: [
         {{ file: '{$video-rtmp-href}' }},
         {{ file: '{$video-hls-href}' }}
       ],
         image: '{$image-href}'
       }}],
      width: '100%',
      height: '90%',
      aspectratio: '16:9',
      primary: "html5",
      stretching: "fill"
     }};   
       
     jwplayer('video-player').setup(options);   
    
     function dialogOpen() {{
      $("#video-player-modal").dialog({{
      resizable: true, 
      width: '65%',
      open: function(event, ui) {{
        jwplayer("video-player-modal").setup(options);
      }}
      }})
    }};
</script>
 <div>
 <a href="javascript:dialogOpen();">
  <img src="/images/video-resize.png"/>
 </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not have a link, unfortunately. I'm working on a development server that can't be accessed out of network.

Comment: Can you put up a test page externally? I need to see something to debug properly.

Comment: It's annoying, but unfortunately I can't put up a test page externally. We'd have to ask our IT department to punch a hole in the firewall to give temporary public access to the development site, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I seemed to have fixed the second problem from my original question by adding the .remove() method to the close event like so:

```
 function dialogOpen() {{
  $("#video-player-modal").dialog({{
    open: function(event, ui) {{
     jwplayer("video-player-modal").setup(options);
    }},
    autoOpen: true,
    resizable: true, 
    close: function(event, ui) {{
      jwplayer("video-player-modal").remove();
    }}
  }})
}};
```

BUT, I'm still having the problem when you first click the link to open the dialog, the dialog window is blank until you actually click on it, then the video shows and plays fine. Does anyone have any ideas for this problem?

Comment: Nice, that definitely works. Maybe for the 2nd issue you should do an entire new setup() when the first click the link?

Comment: I'm doing a new setup() in the dialog open event. Are you suggesting to call setup() outside of the dialog?

Comment: Try to call it first, but have it hidden. I do that in JW Box.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in using this.

Script:

https://github.com/emaxsaun/jwbox

Demo:

http://www.pluginsbyethan.com/github/jwbox.html

Comment: Is there a way to allow the user to click and drag to resize the lightbox window? This looks good, but if there isn't an option to resize the lightbox I don't think it'll work for us.

Comment: The lightbox will resize if the browser is resized, but there isn't an option to resize the lightbox itself or drag it. That might be a good feature to add, though!